# Convert VAPID public and private server key to PEM file for Web Push in Rust

Tags: rust, certificate, pem, web-push

I currently have used Web Push in Node and have my VAPID keys in the following format

```
{"publicKey":"BDrsEIWlTy1YTAZxpkN1f1C0EcuCjL15j8lxS3KaXzDE_BvlWIHEIGdmsP3hfiiG3ldbF89pWEc6foyFxSOe5es","privateKey":"lDLZKT9oZF07KJYWBZU2zlHfszrK4p9tFtxM-ihpVqs"}
```

I am now trying to send Web Push in Rust with the following library
https://github.com/pimeys/rust-web-push

But in this library they want keys as a private and public PEM file, how do I convert my keys?

Comment: I hope that's just a test key and not an important one, because you just published the private key on the Internet…

Comment: You can use this online tool to convert your VAPID keys to PEM format: https://pushpad.xyz/convert_vapid_keys Then you can use the keys in PEM format with your Rust library.

Comment: Haha no that is just an example, not my real key XD @Jmb

Comment: Can I trust that site @collimarco, I also saw that site but would prefer to run the code myself

Comment: @HugoPersson I am the developer, we are a company based in Italy... so yes you can trust it, we don't collect any information. The key is just converted and never stored.

Comment: @collimarco does there exist any way to run this locally without internet?